# UIImageView showing UIPopOver

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uipopover

I would like to fire up this event:

```
- (IBAction)profilePop:(id)sender
{
    ProfileViewController * profile = [[ProfileViewController alloc] init];
    UIImageView * temp = ((UIImageView *)sender);
    profile.uid =  [[[posts objectAtIndex:((UIImageView *)sender).tag] creator] mid];
    NSLog(@"profile id %@", profile.uid);
    UIPopoverController * profilePop  = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:profile];
    [profilePop presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(temp.frame.origin.x+temp.frame.size.width, temp.frame.origin.y + temp.frame.size.height/2, profile.view.frame.size.width, profile.view.frame.size.height) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight animated:YES];
}
```

when a user taps on an UIImageView. All I am trying to do is to show a popover when an UIImageView is clicked and it is shown to the right of the UIImageView. I see that UIImageView doesn't have an addAction attribute from it as it's not a subclass of UIControl. I did some research that I might probably have to use a UIButton instead. Is this true? Is there a way to do this using UIImageView so I don't have to rewrite the code again? I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First.

you could get the touch on any object, which has super class as `UIView`.

if you see the [UIImageView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) in apple documentation.

```
UIView : UIResponder : NSObject
```

[UIResponder](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has function to get the touches. So implement the below functions in your view class and detect the touches on your `UIImageView` .

```
– touchesBegan:withEvent:
– touchesMoved:withEvent:
– touchesEnded:withEvent:
– touchesCancelled:withEvent:
```

Second:

you could also create the `UITapGestureRecognizer`  for `UIImageView`.

Check the below blog tutorial.

[Working with UIGestureRecognizers](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/10/14/working-with-uigesturerecognizers/)

EDITED:

Use below code :

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]             initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
[tapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[tapRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[MyImageView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

if user tap once, **tapped** function will be called , So you **tabbed** function implemntation should be look like below

```
 -(void)tapped:(id)sender
     {

       NSLog(@"See a tap gesture");

         ProfileViewController * profile = [[ProfileViewController alloc] init];
         UIImageView * temp = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender view];
        profile.uid =  [[[posts objectAtIndex:((UIImageView *)sender).tag] creator] mid];
        NSLog(@"profile id %@", profile.uid);
        UIPopoverController * profilePop  = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:profile];
      [profilePop presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(temp.frame.origin.x+temp.frame.size.width, temp.frame.origin.y + temp.frame.size.height/2, profile.view.frame.size.width, profile.view.frame.size.height) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight animated:YES];
    }
```

Comment: can you be a bit more specific in how I can apply this?

Comment: would it cause a slowdown if I added a UIGestureRecognizer for each cell?

Answer (score 0):

What about using an [UIButton](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html) instead and using the class method to add your UIImage to it.

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a UIButton of type custom, don't give it any text or image, give it a clear background, and the same frame as your image view.  Then add your target/selector to the button and it will appear to the user they are tapping the image view, when they are actually tapping an invisible button.  This should take about 3 minutes to set up in IB, so I don't think you'll need to rewrite your code again.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Tap Gesture recognizer and attach it to the UIImageView.

```
// By now imageView exists!
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
[tapGesture release];
```

Now the `handleTapGesture` will be quite similar to your `-profilePop:`

Since you are talking of pop over controllers, I assume you already have gesture recognizers available.

Comment: does this mean I have to add this to every UIImageView in each cell?

Comment: or should I add this at my UITableViewCell subclass

Comment: each cell? is this part of a table view?

Comment: but then the action that handles the tap needs to be in the subclass of this UITableViewCell.. what if I just add this during the cellForRowAtIndexPath>

Comment: I was going to suggest the same had you not subclassed `UITableViewCell`. Since there will be cell reuse, make sure you clear existing gesture recognizers before adding a new one.

Comment: I did try using this UITapGestureRecognizer and change handleTapGesture with profilePop, but it didn't work. why is this